# Pure CSS Accordion Works in Demo, Not in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using the HTML and CSS of a Pure CSS accordion that works perfectly in the demo.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/fivera/pen/yboeE

But I can't get it to work on my WordPress website. See here: http://webdesigncustomizations.com/accordion-portfolio.

I checked the rest of the CSS on my site for compatibility issues and I couldn't find anything that was causing the issue. Could anyone pinpoint the issue?

Thank you!

Clare

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not CSS, unless other CSS rules overide the ones in the file. Have you checked?

The problem is most likely in your theme, either your header and/or sidebar. It could be something really simple, finding the error is the hard part. Try validating your HTML.

If you had posted the entire thing I might have been able to help you more.

Comment: I would have posted all of the code, but I used the exact code in from the demo in my website without changing any of it, and it's right in the demo link. I also can't post all the code to my WordPress site. Wish I could. Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is, something else might be messing with it. I have no doubt you did the accordion right. It's the rest of your theme.

Comment: Thanks Michelle, I completely agree with that. Unfortunately I don't know exactly what I did wrong. So I will try to flush out the cause of it, but I'm not sure what could be the problem. I'll do some trial and error. Thank you!

Comment: I validated the HTML. It involved removing a plugin and adding alt tags and fixing break tags. The rendering of the Pure CSS accordion did not change. I'm wondering what the issue is and if there's a way to fix it.

Comment: It could be your other scripts messing with that script.